# Autocomplete doesn't work on cloned fields

Tags: jquery

I have a list of items that are added or removed based on the requirement so I close the fieldset, and I need autocomplete on those, but it only works on the first input field, not the cloned ones although I'm calling it on focus:

```
$("input[name*='autocomplete]").on("focus", function() {
    $(this).autocomplete({
        ...
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Events can only be bound to elements that are already in the DOM when the page is loaded. For dynamically added elements, you can use `on()` to delegate the event from a static parent element:

```
$(document).on("focus", "input[name*='autocomplete']", function () {
  $(this).autocomplete(....);
});
```

Instead of `document` every parent element can be used to delegate the event. If your inputs will e.g. be added in a container with the id `form`:

```
$("#form").on("focus", "input[name*='autocomplete']", function () {
  $(this).autocomplete(....);
});
```

Example [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vs36mg2q/), and for reference: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: `.focus()` is a shorthand for `.on("focus", handler)` no?

Comment: @3zzy You're right, but there `.focus()` is attached to the element of `element.focus()`. Here, `on()` is used to delegate the `focus()` / `.on("focus", handler)` event from an element in the DOM to child elements that can be added later, so `element.on("focus", target, handler)` results in `target.focus(handler)` / `target.on("focus", handler)`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("input[name*='autocomplete']").on("focus", function() {
    $(this).autocomplete({
        ...
    });
});
```

You were missing a single quote.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Someone's gonna bite his own butt if this _really_ is the issue. But I doubt it :-) Then it would not work on the first input as well...

Comment: HA Could be the issue, but then again I don't see all of his code. I'm just guessing this is a factor seeing that you do indeed need a single quote there lol @arkascha

Comment: Typically people do not post the _exact_ code they use. Instead they post a reduced version which makes sense and is actually preferred. But you are right that in the given code the quote is missing.

Comment: Well it would work on the first one regardless because he's not adding or removing the first input field. The ones he's having trouble with are the ones he's "cloned" so to speak @arkascha

Comment: Nothing but silence so far... hmmm @arkascha

Comment: Yes guys, it is the 'reduced' version and the missing `'` is not the issue. I even tried placing it at the bottom of the page but the problem remains, the autocomplete doesn't work on cloned fieldsets.